# LDAP using python

Tags: python, bash, shell, ldap, python-2.x

Can someone help me to convert the below shell script into python(**version 2.6.6**)

**Shell code:**

```
ldapsearch -x -h ldap.bbc.network.lcl -p 3477 -b "DC=bbc,DC=network,DC=lcl" -D "CN=LDAP\, Mine,OU=Resource Accounts,OU=Enterprise,DC=bbc,DC=network,DC=lcl" -w passwd $1
```

**Python code:**

```
import ldap

l = ldap.initialize('ldap://ldap.bbc.network.lcl')

username = "DC=bbc, DC=network, DC=lcl"

password = "passwd"

l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3

l.simple_bind_s(username, password)

base = ""

scope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE

filter = "cn=" + "*" + 'Mine' + "*"

retrieve_attributes = None

result_id = l.search(base, scope, filter, retrieve_attributes)
```

pls hep me to convert it into python

Comment: is the user name and password is correct which i am using in python  same as shell ?
Because I am getting invalid credentials error

Comment: from the shell code can i know , what's the username and password

Comment: can i know , wthat is meant by  "-b "  here